# Creating WebAPI to allow a string to be passed with '/' characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm creating a WebApi in ASP.NET. I want one of my get methods to allow a string to be passed into it. This string will function as a path to a branch in TFS where I'll do a `QueryHistory` to return its history.

In my `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Branches",
    routeTemplate: "api/branches/{fullPath}",
    defaults: new { controller = "branches", fullPath = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

In my controller.cs file:

```
// GET api/branches/$/Project/Branches/Path/To-This-Branch
public string Get(Uri fullPath)
{
    string output = "";
    NetworkCredential cre = new NetworkCredential("COSMO\\pd-srv", pWord);
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://fortknox:8080/tfs/PD"), cre);
    var service = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    string s = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(fullPath);

    var latestChange = service.QueryHistory(s, RecursionType.None, 1);

    //output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(latestChange);
    //return a json formatted string containing the full history of the branch path passed in
    return "value";
}
```

I've tried multiple ways, just seems like when I pass in a uriEncoded parameter the `UnescapeDataString` only accepts strings so it doesn't work. If I pass in the string I get an error due to the `'/'`.

How can I pass this path from my javascript to my `Get()` call in my api?

Comment: "If I pass in the string I get an error due to the '/'." - What is the error?

Comment: "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I believe its actually trying to look the that exact location and cannot find a route for all those '/' in the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this as well in the past and solved it by converting "/" to "!" and then converting back in the API.  You could substitute any character(s) there... you just need to get rid of the "/"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{*fullPath}` in the end of your route template to match the `fullPath` using a wildcard expression.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Branches",
    routeTemplate: "api/branches/{*fullPath}",
    defaults: new { controller = "branches", fullPath = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

See [MSDN: Handling a Variable Number of Segments in a URL Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: by using this technique, it looks like i will then not be able to add any other parameter on to the end. Correct?

Comment: Indeed. It is the last parameter :)

Comment: but if i wanted to pass another parameter after this like say a query to this branch, i could not because my route would not be able to tell where one parameter ends and the next begins

Comment: It might be possible if you split them using words like `/{*first}/second/{*second}`. Not sure though.

Comment: although your solution could work, I already had to replace a period in the path so @Jeff solution works best for me. Thank you though for your insight

Comment: Then just URL encode the contents. Replacing makes it a mess in the end.

Comment: using the encodeuricomponent function does not encode the period character. Therefore it still breaks the link. Believe me, I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try call Get method:

api/branches?fullPath="directory1/directory2"